# Which control can be used in order to display a dynamic form (with various types of data)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsmatrix

I'm facing the following problems:

- We have meta data for items, each item can be a different type of NSControl, currently NSTokenField and NSTextField, but we might need NSCombo or other types.
  I need to build a form in which each entry will have a label and an editable control.
  this form has to be built dynamically since the items are retrieved from the server.

I've implemented it with NSMatrix, and apart from it looking pretty shabby, I'm faced with some visual issues I don't know how to solve.

The visual issue is every time I move the mouse over the NSTextFieldCell the tokens get drawn on the top left corner of the NSMatrix form.

now, I'm considering moving to another type of control,

I've googled for few hours, and found the following controls:
NSForm, 
NSMatirx (parent of NSForm),
NSCollectionView,
NSTableView

which one of these is the most appropriate for this task?

I hope I am clear since I wanted to add pictures, but it wouldn't let me due to lack of "reputation points".

Thanks for your help,
Eyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTokenField` is a subclass of `NSTextField` so you could use an `NSTableView` to display them.

You could also draw a custom `NSCell` with all elements in it. When each "item" has a different **number** of elements then this becomes a bit more complicated though.

Comment: does NSTableView provide editing functionality?

each items should be editable by the user, and the label should be just text without editing.

Comment: Yes. You could have an `NSTableView` with two columns. One with an `NSTextFieldCell` and one with an `NSTokenFieldCell`. The `NSTextFieldCell` can be set to editable in Interface Builder. For the `NSTokenFieldCell` you'd have to add an `NSTextFieldCell` and change its class to `NSTokenFieldCell` in the identity inspector. Then, it too, can be made editable in Interface Builder. But they both are editable by default.